# Use NuxtJs on server-side to Hydrate a Cordova client

Tags: javascript, cordova, nuxt.js

I'm trying to upgrade an old mobile application written in vanilla Javascript+React hosted on Cordova. This application leverages a simple api on the server-side:

- when the app requires a page, sends a request to the server
- the server elaborate the request, fetch the resources, and then reply with a complete HTML+JS. The Javascript is a ReactJs view compiled with Gulp/Browserify
- the app takes the reply and stores it in a local Sqlite DB, then mount the received code and the view become reactive.
- if the user requests a view but has no connectivity, the app search though the Sqlite db wether there is a cached view and uses it instead of requesting a fresh copy from the server.

When developing, the React JSX code is immediately compiled to a vanilla JS so, when in production, the api only needs to merge the vanilla JS with the HTML template. Plus, adding new features and fixing bugs is quite easy, because each user essentially download any updated view, each time he enters in it.

The problems with this approach are:

- developing is painful because of the continuous compilation
- a "base" part of the application resides on Cordova assets (basically the utilities to fetch from server, caching etc) and fixing this parts needs a new app release or ugly override patches
- the caching feature often causes problems to the Sqlite database (which is used also for other stuff on the app); as a result, the DB sometimes corrupts and the user must clear the app data.
- we would like to get rid of React

We already used NuxtJs for generating static sites, and it's great, but in this case I cannot leverage the SSG because the app should be almost completely served from the api, so we can keep the easy-feature-and-fix stuff.
I never used NustJs SSR and wonder if could be suitable for my use case, for example, could I spin up a NuxtJs instance on server-side which generates the html output and hydrate a barely empty Javascript client on Cordova? Is there a better way to accomplish this task? Should I use only Vue instead?
Thanks